# Equivariant quantum cohomology of conical symplectic resolutions

Tags: gromov-witten-theory, geometric-representation-theory, holomorphic-symplectic, quantum-cohomology

There is a couple of papers on this [Braverman, Maulik, Oblomkov, Okounkov, Pandharipande] where authors calculate quantum cohomology for various conical symplectic resolutions. The language in these paper is pretty algebro-geometric, whereas my view of quantum cohomology comes from symplectic geometry. Therefore, instead of ''counting rational curves'' I think of counting holomorphic=symplectic spheres.

Though, in the exact setup as this is (holomorphic symplectic form in conical symplectic resolutions is exact) there are no nontrivial holomorphic curves. So the quantum cohomology = singular cohomology as a ring.

However, in these papers, authors deal with equivariant quantum cohomology  rather than the usual one (these spaces always come with a group action). So, as a vector space it is just equivariant cohomology tensored with appropriate power series ring, but I remain puzzled with the **ring multiplication in it** - thinking from symplectic viewpoint, does it counts some sort of ''equivariant holomorphic = symplectic spheres''?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I don't understand why you say that there are no holomorphic curves - a typical example of such a space is $T^*{\mathbb C}{\mathbb P}^1$ and it perfectly has non-trivial holomoprhic curves. What is true though, is that you can choose a different complex structure (still compatible with the same real symplectic form) so that all holomorphic curves go away. That's one of the possible explanations why on usual (non-equivariant) quantum cohomology the multiplication is equal to the ordinary (non-quantum) multiplication. Hoewever, the point is that there is no complex (or even almost complex) structure with this property in which the ${\mathbb C}^*$-action remains holomoprhic. Basically, the correct way to think about equivariant cohomology (in any context) is to think about cohomology of the quotient. Of course, this is tricky when the action is not free, but philosophically that's what it is. So, you have to work with complex structures which are invariant under ${\mathbb C}^*$, and then you do have curves. There is still an issue of defining the right virtual fundamental class on the corresponding moduli space.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I see what you are saying. The misunderstanding came from different definitions of $QH*-$I count symplectic spheres while you count holomorphic. When those two structures are compatible it is the same thing. So, I thought that the symplectic form which is considered to calculate $QH^*$ is the one that comes from the complex symplectic form of symplectic resolution (as its real/imaginary part). That one is exact form, hence doesn't have non-trivial symplectic spheres - this would indeed give $QH^*=H^*$ as a ring.

Comment: E.g. in the example $T^* \mathbb{C}P^1$ that you've mentioned, zero section $\mathbb{C} P^1$ is Lagrangian with respect to this symplectic form, so orthogonal to being symplectic.

Comment: So, given what you said, the symplectic structure which is used here is the one orthogonal to the complex symplectic one (which we know exists, e.g. using the fact that these spaces are hyperkahler actually). This one is indeed compatible with the holomorphic structure $I$ which is invariant under $\mathbb{C}^*$-action. In your example, with respect to that symplectic structure, $\mathbb{C} P^1$ is symplectic hence holomorphic as well.

Comment: I am not aware of any definition of quantum cohomology which counts symplectic spheres. To the best of my knowledge the standard definition of GW invariants in symplectic geometry context goes as follows - you choose a generic almost complex structure compatible with the symplectic structure and the "count" (in the appropriate sense) holomorphic curves. I don't think that there is a definition with symplectic spheres.

Comment: My bad - what I wanted to say is because holomorphic spheres are also symplectic, you are counting symplectic spheres. Though since the contrary is not true, it is definitely not the same count. Could you please explain (or refer to a reference) why you can choose a different complex structure (still compatible with the same real symplectic form) so that all holomorphic curves go away?

Comment: It is known (due to Kaledin and Namikawa) that as an algebraic symplectic variety any conical symplectic resolution has a (topologically trivial) deformation whose base is $H^2$ of that variety (with complex coefficients) and whose generic fiber is an affine algebraic (hence it doesn't have any proper holomorphic curves).

Comment: I mean to say "whose generic fiber is an affine algebraic variety"

Comment: I see. Many thanks for the explanations!